# ImportError: No module named flask in docker container

Tags: python, docker, flask

I have a flask app whose flask is among its dependecies, which runs fine in local and binds to the default port 5000. My project structure is the following :

https://i.stack.imgur.com/GZhiI.png

Here is my app.py (main) code :

```
import os
from flask import Flask
from flask_cors import CORS
from config import config_by_name
import api


def create_app(config_name):
    """Creates the flask app and initialize its component"""

    app = Flask(__name__)
    app.config.from_object(config_by_name[config_name])
    CORS(app)
    app.register_blueprint(api.smthg)

    return app

app = create_app(os.getenv('APP_ENV') or 'dev')
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(port=app.config["PORT"], threaded=True)
```

The problem is that when I deploy this in docker, I get the error code `ImportError: No module named flask` when `docker logs cont-test`

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "app.py", line 2, in <module>
    from flask import Flask
ImportError: No module named flask
```

Below is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu:latest

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y software-properties-common
RUN apt-get update && add-apt-repository ppa:deadsnakes/ppa -y
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y python

# Install pip from standard ubuntu packages
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install unixodbc-dev --yes
RUN apt-get -y install python3-pip
RUN pip3 install --upgrade pipenv

COPY ./api/ ./services/ config.py Pipfile Pipfile.lock app.py ./

RUN pipenv install --system --deploy --ignore-pipfile 

ENTRYPOINT ["python"]

CMD ["app.py" ]
```

Flask is existing in my `Pipfile.lock` as well :

```
"flask": {
            "hashes": [
                "sha256:59da8a3170004800a2837844bfa84d49b022550616070f7cb1a659682b2e7c9f",
                "sha256:e1120c228ca2f553b470df4a5fa927ab66258467526069981b3eb0a91902687d"
            ],
            "index": "pypi",
            "version": "==2.0.3"
        },
```

Here are the steps I am doing to deploy
`docker build -t="imgtest" .`

As far as I know the above runs fine. Now, let's start the server in a container:

```
docker run -it -d  --name cont-test imgtest
c976d1823c6ad8a19c84485176633fcec45cdabd3d7e7b2b13de88118fa34eea
```

Now `docker ps` --> It's not running.

```
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE     COMMAND   CREATED   STATUS    PORTS     NAMES
```

What am I doing wrong please?

Comment: Is flask in your Pipfile.lock? You're ignoring the Pipfile in your install, so the Pipfile.lock is used instead

Comment: Yes, it does exist. I've updated my post adding flask section in my Pipfile.lock. Thx for the remark :)

Comment: You might want to look at the log output of your container, to find out why it is not running https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/logging/

Comment: @mfit thx for your remark, I have added the outcome from my docker logs command, a mention for the `ImportError: No module named flask` error.

Comment: Have you tried adding an explicit `pip install flask` to your Dockerfile? That may help clarify that your issue is in the `pipenv` install

Comment: Now it's showing an error regarding my interactive modules in the project `ImportError: No module named api`. I believe the problem is coming from my python interpreter or sys path. Thus, this kind of errors doesn't show when I run my app localy  `python app.py` :(